# application not reading from user.config

Tags: c#, console-application

I have Visual studio solution which has both asp.net and console application project. In console application i have app.config which i declared like this and it should read from user.config

```
  <appSettings  file="user.config">

  </appSettings>
```

Here is my user.config

```
<appSettings>

  <add key="MyKey" value="Test" />

</appSettings>
```

Then in my code i try to fetch like

```
 string myKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"];
```

But it gives me null. What is issue here and how to resolve it?

**Update 1**
  I have set Copy to Output directory to Copy Always for both app.config and user.config

Comment: Are you sure the user.config is present in application directory? Did you make vs copy it to output directory every time? Why don't you try specifying an absolute path to that file.

Comment: Do you have an <configuration> section in appconfig and made an System.Configuration reference?

Comment: @Bebolicious offcourse i have configuration section in app.config. I simply didnt included on SO

Comment: @James You can't blame them for asking when it isn't included in the question.

Comment: @Amy no didnt blamed. I just told that i didnt included in SO

Comment: Id suggest debugging the path its using for the user.config to be sure it is in the place you were thinking.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a problem that can no longer be reproduced.  The OP said in a [comment on the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112945/application-not-reading-from-user-config#comment98860103_56113039) that this is not an issue any longer.

Comment: @Amy dont close. I tried solution of Gabriel and it worked.

Comment: @James What do you mean you tried a solution from Gabriel and it worked?  You said, "**i dont know what happened** but looks like its now working "  Why would you say that when you know what happened?  Nevermind, I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: @Amy iset proprty copy to output folder to copy always. It was not case before. I added that after Gabriel told. At first it didnt worked but then it worked. Not sure what went wrong for first time but its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.config` must be present in the same directory as `app.config`; if the file is not found at runtime, it will use the value from `app.config` (which doesn't exist), so you get `null`. Make sure `user.config` is configured to be copied to the output directory on build, and the build action is set to "None".

After you build the project, are both `config` files present in the output directory?

Comment: both user.config and app.config are on same level

Comment: @James Are they both "copy to output folder" on build?

Comment: @Amy yes i set Copy To output Directory to copy always

Comment: @James Please add that information to your question so people don't need to hunt through comments for a complete picture of your question.

Comment: i dont know what happened but looks like its now working :)